# Awk: Remove duplicate lines with conditions

Tags: awk, duplicates, line

I have a tab-delimited text file with 8 columns:

```
Erythropoietin Receptor Integrin Beta 4 11.7    9.7 164 195 19  3.2
Erythropoietin Receptor Receptor Tyrosine Phosphatase F 10.8    2.6 97  107 15  3.2
Erythropoietin Receptor Leukemia Inhibitory Factor Receptor 12.0    3.6 171 479 14  3.2
Erythropoietin Receptor Immunoglobulin 9    10.4    3.1 100 108 24  3.3
Erythropoietin Receptor Collagen Alpha 1 Xx 10.7    2.7 93  105 18  3.3
Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor  Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor 5    11.4    3.2 114 114 25  1.7
Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor  Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor 14   11.1    2.1 99  100 28  1.8
Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor  Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor 1B   10.9    4.9 133 162 29  1.9
Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor  Tumor Necrosis Factor Receptor 11A  11.5    5.1 130 166 25  1.9
```

The first and second column contain protein names and the 8th column contains the "distance" score between each protein pair. I would like to remove the lines containing duplicate protein pairs and keep only the pair with the lowest distance (the lowest value in the 8th column). This means that for the pair Protein A-Protein B I would like to remove all occurrences except the one with the lowest distance score. The pair is considered duplicate even if the protein names are swapped (in different columns). This means that Protein A Protein B is the same as Protein B Protein A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this would be the **final** update  ^_^

```
kent$  awk -F'\t' '{if($1$2 in a){
                if($8<a[$1$2]){
                        a[$1$2]=$8;r[$1$2]=$0;
                }
        }else if ($2$1 in a){
                if($8<a[$2$1]){
                        a[$2$1] = $8;r[$2$1] = $0;
                }
        }else{
                a[$1$2]=$8; r[$1$2]=$0;
        }
} END{for(x in r)print r[x]}' yourFile
```

Comment: In my case this produces an empty file with the right number of lines. Maybe because columns 1 and 2 contain spaces...

Comment: spaces are not the problem, see my updated test. with spaces. are you sure the line is TAB separated?

Comment: Yes, I have replaced the spaces with underscores and the problem persists. Could it be the float values in 8th column?

Comment: see my updated float number test. float values are not the problem either.

Comment: Weird. I have GNU Awk 3.1.7. And, in fact, your script produces a file that it is a few lines shorter than the original file, meaning that probably it is doing something. The problem is that lines are empty (they contain just line breaks)...

Comment: i think I found the error. see my new updated answr and try please.

Comment: glad to help. I just missed a "=" sign. :D

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (untested):

```
awk -F'\t' 'END {
  for (r in rec) print rec[r] 
  }
{
  if (mina[$1, $2] < $NF || minb[$2, $1] < $NF) {
    mina[$1, $2] = $NF; minb[$2, $1] = $NF
    rec[$1, $2] = $0
    }  
  }' infile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question: Where is this reading the value in the 8th column?

Comment: $NF is tha last column, which in your case is the 8th column.